# How to trigger dotcover code coverage analysis on source build and generate report

Tags: dotcover

I am having main project file and testing project file.

when i build the solution i need to automatically trigger dotcover code coverage analysis and generate a report in html format.

It should happen in every build in visual studio.

I need suggestion regarding this to implement this in efficient way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio, you can add Post-build event command line.
Regarding to post build event, You can run dotcover coverage analysis from the command line. You can find related information in below links

how to add **post build** event to Visual Studio.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx

How to run **DotCover** code coverage from command line.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/10.0/Running_Coverage_Analysis_from_the_Command_LIne.html

Comment: Thanks for your help.